# How to display Matlab's ode45 results in real time?

Tags: matlab, real-time, ode

Let's suppose that we have the following solver for a system of first-order ODEs:

```
   % func.m
   function dydt = func(t,y)
   dydt = [y(2); (1-y(1)^2)*y(2)-y(1)];
```

and the main code:

```
% solver.m
tspan=0:1:10;
[t,y] = ode45(@func,tspan,[2; 0]);
```

How to display  in real-time the results, y1(t) and y2(t), for each time step t that the ode45 makes (t=0,1,2,...,10), without waiting for the whole code to finish?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`OutputFcn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html#input_argument_namevalue_OutputFcn) ode solver option should be used. For example, to plot the solution vs time, the built-in output function `odeplot` can be used:

```
options= odeset('OutputFcn',@odeplot);
[t,y] = ode45(@func,[0 200],[2; 0],options);
```

You can use your own output function. Here is an example:

```
myOutputFcn= @(t,y,flag)fprintf('t= %s y=  %s\n',mat2str(t),mat2str(y))*0;
options= odeset('OutputFcn',myOutputFcn);
[t,y] = ode45(@f,0:1:10,[2; 0],options);
```

Comment: I changed the code to this: tspan=0:1:10; [t,y] = ode45(@func,tspan,[2; 0],options); How to print t and y1(t), y2(t), for t=0,1,2,...,10? Your code gives some strange results for t and y. Here y has two columns.

Comment: @Andyk Sorry, there was some bugs when using `fprintf`. I have corrected the answer

Comment: Why did you multiply the fprintf by 0?

Comment: The output function should return `0` to continue and `1` to stop; `fprintf` returns the number of bytes writen (not equal to `0`). The simpliest way to return zero in our case (from an anonymous function) is just to multiply this number by `0`